# AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'lower' when converting confusion matrix to data frame

Tags: h2o

I am trying to convert the confusion matrix to a python 2D list so I can access the components.

I am getting an error when trying to convert a confusion matrix to a data frame.

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
import pandas as pd

h2o.init()

training_file = "AirlinesTrain.csv"
train = h2o.import_file(training_file)
response_col = "IsDepDelayed"
distribution = "multinomial"
project_name = "airlines"
problem_type = "binary-classification"
predictors = train.columns
gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds=3,
                                    distribution=distribution)
gbm.train(x=predictors,
           y=response_col,
           training_frame=train)
print("gbm.confusion_matrix(train).as_data_frame()")
print(gbm.confusion_matrix(train).as_data_frame())#This errors AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

NOTE: if I use the cars dataset, there are no errors:

```
cars = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")
cars["cylinders"] = cars["cylinders"].asfactor()
#r = cars[0].runif()
#train = cars[r > .2]
#valid = cars[r <= .2]
train=cars
response_col = "cylinders"
distribution = "multinomial"
predictors = ["displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue.  Seems there may be something wrong in the docs as it mentions you can pass a H2OFrame.
https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html

However i think if you passed `train=True` it would work

```
print(gbm.confusion_matrix(train=True).as_data_frame())
```